# delphi how to keep program connected to a site using tIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy

i have a problem i can connect using tIdhttp to the site i want without any problem but the problem is i cant connect from other button.

i have declared those variables outside the function .. tought this gonna help but it didnt

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
   HTTP : TIDHTTP;
 Cookie : TidCookieManager;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
```

and this in the function

```
    HTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(NIL);
     Cookie := TidCookieManager.Create(nil);



     HTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; Acoo Browser 1.98.744; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
     HTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
     HTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
     HTTP.AllowCookies := True;
     HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
     HTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
     HTTP.CookieManager := Cookie;
     HTTP.RedirectMaximum := 15;

    Data := TStringList.Create;
 Page := TStringList.Create;

 Data.Add('LoginForm[username]=xxxLoginForm[password]=xxx&LoginForm[rememberMe]=0');
Page.Text :=  HTTP.Post('http://somesite.com/login.html',Data);


 If Pos('>Logout', Page.Text) = 0 Then Result := False
 else Result := True;



 Page.Free;
 Data.Free;
// HTTP.Free;
end;
```

button2

```
HTTP.Get('http://somesite.cc/info/523364d0/'); // this does not work it show that im not connected ..but the function already connected to the site.
```

in button1 i can connect(Logged in to a site) using my function successfully then i click in button2 using HTTP.get to get file but it fail it shows that im not logged in 
so how i can keep my program connected so i can only call get page(in other buttons) wihtout logging in again .

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please paste full code of the unit.

Comment: Okay i have posted all codes in the function

Comment: Are you able to login using a web browser?  If so, then use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to capture that HTTP data, and then you can code `TIdHTTP` to replicate it.  You are likely missing something that the webbrowser sends and/or the webserver requires.

Comment: You can but you can't?

Comment: This is probably just a typo, but your host names don't match (`somesite.cc` and `somesite.com`), also it seems odd that you're posting to a HTML page. Ensure you're posting to the action for the form. You sure that login is succeeding? Even if you could put all the params on a single line, you're missing the `&` separator between the first and second param.

Answer (score 1):

Your login data is being formatted wrong.  Not only are you missing a `&` between the username and password fields, but you should not be putting everything in a single `TStringList` entry to begin with.  `TIdHTTP` expects each field to be its own entry in the `TStringList`, and then it will encode and concatenate the values together when formatting the HTTP request.

In other words, change this:

> Data.Add('LoginForm[username]=xxxLoginForm[password]=xxx&LoginForm[rememberMe]=0');

to this:

```
Data.Add('LoginForm[username]=xxx');
Data.Add('LoginForm[password]=xxx');
Data.Add('LoginForm[rememberMe]=0');
```

If that still does not work, then the problem has to be related to the HTTP session.  Either the server is sending a cookie upon login that `TIdCookieManager` is rejecting, or `TIdCookieManager` is not sending the cookie back on subsequent requests to the same HTTP server, or maybe subsequent requests need to specify a `Referer` that is set to the previous URL (some servers do require that).

Comment: my code works fine, i call my function in button ONE and logged there successfully and i want to get a page in button TWO but its says im logged in but in button in my function im logged in

Comment: my code works fine, i call my function in button ONE and logged there successfully and i want to get a page in button TWO but its says im NOT logged in but in button ONE in my function im logged in i dont want to log in every time i visit a page in every button

Comment: You need to separate the `TStringList` contents. It does not matter if what you have "works", what I showed is what `TIdHTTP` expects (I should know, I wrote it). Also, as Marcus commented, there are some other issues with your code logic (requesting URLs in different domains, posting to an HTML page, etc) that suggest what you showed may not be your actual code. Is it really? Did you sniff a webbrowser's traffic to compare to the `TIdHTTP` traffic, like I  suggested? Without that, it is hard to know what actually "works" correctly and what is missing.